# jQuery calculate total in input

Tags: jquery, forms

I have some code which calculates the totals of the input in a row and then adds to a to grand total at the end, this is currently working code below:

```
$(":text[name='qty[]'],:text[name='rate[]']").keyup(function()
{
    var totalamount = 0.00;
    $("ul.rowData").each(function()
    {
        var quantity = +$(this).find(":text[name='qty[]']").val() || 0;
        var rate = +$(this).find(":text[name='rate[]']").val() || 0;
        var subtotal = quantity * rate;
        $(this).find(":text[name='price[]']").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
        totalamount += subtotal;
    });
    $("#totalprice").val(totalamount.toFixed(2));
});
```

Now I then have an add row button which adds a row of fields:

```
$('.mainForm').find('.addItem').click(function()
{
    $('.invoiceItems').append('<ul class="rowData">' +
    '<li class="txtLg"><span class="sep">Item:</span><input type="text" name="item[]" maxlength="255" value=""></li>' +
    '<li class="txtLg"><span class="sep">Description:</span><input type="text" name="description[]" maxlength="255" value=""></li>' +
    '<li class="txtSm"><span class="sep">Rate:</span><input type="text" name="rate[]" maxlength="10" value="0.00"></li>' +
    '<li class="txtSm"><span class="sep">Qty:</span><input type="text" name="qty[]" maxlength="5" value="1"></li>' +
    '<li class="txtSm"><span class="sep">Price:</span><input type="text" name="price[]" maxlength="10" value="0.00"><input type="hidden" name="itemid[]" value="0"></li>' +
    '</ul>').fadeIn(500);
    return false;
});
```

My question is once I click add row the totals in the fields do not get automatically calculated when you add numbers to them. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your bind `$().keyup(function(){}}` is not working with dynamically added to the page elements

```
$(":text[name='qty[]'],:text[name='rate[]']").live('keyup',function(){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They don't get recalculated because there's no code to do that :)

You're basically calculating the total, and adding that into the page.  You need some additional code, to recalculate those totals when the originals are modified.  You'll probably re-use some of the existing code BTW.

Have a look at the `.keyup()` and `.change()` jQuery events.  The former will be triggered every time a key is release, and latter only when an input looses focus.  You'll probably want to use one of both to update the totals field;

```
$('.sep').on('change', function(e) {
  // stuff
});
```